# Logarithmic property justification

Tags: logarithms

I saw this particular line slammed in a proof and it bothers me I can't understand why this is obvious and how would one justify this :
$$
7^{\log (n)}  = n^{\log (7)} $$

Can anyone explain ?

Comment: Hint: try writing $n$ as $e^{\log n}$ and then massaging the resulting expression a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$7^{\ln n}=\exp (\ln 7 \ln n)=n^{\ln 7}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $\log$ of the LHS

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\log{(7^{\log{n}}}) =& (\log{n})(\log{7}) \\ =&
\log{(n^{\log{7}}})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Then removing the log we took earlier we can clearly see $7^{\log{n}} = n^{\log{7}}.$

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you need to make a comment about the $\log$ function. For example, $(+1)^2=(-1)^2$ but you can't just remove the square to derive $+1=-1$...

Answer (score 0):

$$7^{\log n}=7^{\frac{\log_7(n)}{\log_7(10)}}=7^{\log_7(n^{1/\log_7(10)})}=n^{1/\log_7(10)}=n^{\log_7(7)/\log_7(10)}=n^{\log(7)}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone is missing the point that the *definition* for $x^\alpha$ for irrational $\alpha$ is

$$x^\alpha =e^{\alpha\ln x}.$$

This is why the other answers make sense.

Comment: I think actually that's exactly the property that the accepted answer used. Answers that took different approaches ended up more complicated, I think.

Comment: I agree but it is a definition rather than a property. We only have $\exp(\ln 7\ln n)=n^{\ln 7}$ by definition of $n^\alpha$ for $\alpha$ irrational.

Comment: I was using the word "property" as a superset of "definition." One could also say this property holds _by definition_.